# fork() execution process

Tags: c, fork

How exactly does fork() work?

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
printf("Hi\n");
int i;
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    printf("Argument %d is %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    fork();
    printf("Forked in for loop increment %d\n", i);
}


return 0;
}
```

gives the following output

> /a.out hello world
>
> Argument 1 is hello
>
> Forked in for loop increment 1
>
> Argument 2 is world
>
> Forked in for loop increment 2
>
> Forked in for loop increment 1
>
> Argument 2 is world
>
> Forked in for loop increment 2
>
> Forked in for loop increment 2

What code does fork execute first, in general. I would like to know the principles of fork() rather than based on just this one example. I could have had multiple arguments on the command line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fork` is a system call, i.e. a library routine that calls into the kernel. When servicing a `fork` call, the kernel creates a new process that executes the same program as the process that called it. The new process starts executing as if *it* had called `fork`; the return value is different from the one in the parent, so you can distinguish the two.

The common idiom for invoking `fork` is:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

switch (pid) {
  case -1:
    /* an error occurred, i.e. no child process created */
    handle_error();
  case 0:
    /* a return value of 0 means we're in the child process */
    do_child_stuff();
    break;  // or _exit()
  default:
    /* we're in the parent; pid is the child's process id */
    do_parent_stuff();
}
```

*How* this works is: the OS makes a near-perfect copy of the process calling `fork` (the PID and some other values are different, but the memory contents start out practically the same and usually the same files are opened in both). The copy is commonly done using so-called copy-on-write (COW) semantics, so there's hardly any actual copying done until one of the processes starts assigning to variables.

Comment: So my print outs are misleading me. A fork() in a for loop is weird to right?

Comment: The order of output in your program is nondeterministic. A `fork` in a loop isn't so strange (you may want to create some *n* number of worker processes), but a bare `fork` where child and parent run the same code is pretty rare. Most of the time, a `fork` is just preparation for a call to `exec`.

Comment: @Helium3 What is weird is code that doesn't store the return value of fork in a variable called something like childpid and then do different things depending on whether it is 0 (in the child), positive (in the parent), or negative (failure). This can happen in a loop or not.

Comment: How would one use these pids? In the switch above would one know what would execute because pid_t pid = fork(); returns the specific pid, or why would there be a possibility that the pid returned could be the child or parent? How does one use the pids as needed afterwards? Is it possible to use some library functions on a pid e.g. (taking a guess here) sleep() or kill(). Can forked processes create forked process recursively for a certain amount of needed processes and keep track of them from the main parent?

Comment: @Helium3: please read the comments in the `switch`. If the pid is zero, we're in the child and we perform "child labor". Else we're in the parent and we (probably) control the child somehow, feed data to it, and eventually `wait` for it to exit. I've never seen recursive forking outside of a fork-bomb and don't see any use for it. It would only set up needless processes waiting for their children to perform work. A simple loop is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Helium3: are you familiar with the `switch` statement?

Comment: yes of course. I just wondered if the pid is set to the failure or success of the process creation, what would force it to not execute -1 or 0 in the switch?

Comment: The pid is not just a success/failure flag as with other system calls. If >0, it's an integer identifying the child process.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that number of process will grow exponentially, so for 100 arguments we are talking about 1267650600228229401496703205376 processes. I hope you have a really strong PC :).

I will answer your comment here, it will maybe help you to understand the fork.

After each loop you will double the number of process. So after N loops you will end up with 2^N process. Or after 100 loops you will end up with that big number I gave you.

Btw, [fork bombs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) are one of the most common DoS attacks around :)

Comment: It was an exaggeration. ;) how do you get to that number?

Comment: Each argument doubles the amount of forked processes. So you'll end up with 2^n processes. For a long time most OS couldn't manage more than 2^16 processes at a time, due to the simple fact that the process id (PID) used to be a 16 bit number. And even if today's OS mostly use 32bit types for the PID, oftenly ther's a 2^16 limit in place. But one seldomly has more than 1000 processes spawned on a system on a time.

Comment: Thanks for the info. @Klark: fork bombs link was interesting thanks.