# fork starts executing form where?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, fork, semaphore

To my previous question about segmentation fault ,I got very useful answers.Thanks for those who have responded.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 printf("hello");
int pid = fork();
wait(NULL);
}
```

output: hellohello.

In this the child process starts executing form the beginning.
If Iam not wrong , then how the program works if I put the sem_open before fork()
(ref answers to :prev questions)

**I need a clear explanation about segmentation fault which happens occasionally and not always. And why not always... If there is any error in coding then it should occur always right...?**

Comment: it starts from `fork()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fork() execution process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010359/fork-execution-process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fork` creates a clone of your process.  Conceptually speaking, all state of the parent also ends up in the child.  This includes:

- CPU registers (including the instruction pointer, which defines where in the code your program is)
- Memory (as an optimization your kernel will most likely mark all pages as copy-on-write, but semantically speaking it should be the same as copying all memory.)
- File descriptors

Therefore...  Your program will not "start running" from anywhere...  All the state that you had when you called `fork` will propagate to the child.  The child will return from `fork` just as the parent will.

As for what you can do after a fork... I'm not sure about what POSIX says, but I wouldn't rely on semaphores doing the right thing after a `fork`.  You might need an inter-process semaphore (see `man sem_open`, or the `pshared` parameter of `sem_init`).  In my experience cross-process semaphores aren't really well supported on free Unix type OS's...  (Example: Some BSDs always fail with `ENOSYS` if you ever try to create one.)

@GregS mentions the duplicated "hello" strings after a fork.  He is correct to say that stdio (i.e. `FILE*`) will buffer in user-space memory, and that a `fork` leads to the string being buffered in two processes.  You might want to call `fflush(stdout); fflush(stderr);` and flush any other important `FILE*` handles before a `fork`.

Comment: @GregS - Yes, you are completely right.  I incorporated this into the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, it starts from the `fork()`, which returns 0 in the child or the child's process ID in the parent.

You see "hello" twice because the standard output is buffered, and has not actually been written at the point of the fork.  Both parent and child then actually write the buffered output.  If you `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()`, you should see it only once.